# Python lambda in lambda

Tags: python, lambda

```
g = lambda x:[lambda x:x*1, lambda x:x*x, lambda x:x*x*x, lambda x:42][x%4](x)

[g(x) for x in xrange(12)]
```

What is the next value of this sequence?

Comment: The line `[x%4](x)` errors out. What are you trying to do in that line?

Comment: Is this a homework or exam question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you try it?

```
>>> g = lambda x:[lambda x:x*1, lambda x:x*x, lambda x:x*x*x, lambda x:42][x%4](x)
>>> [g(x) for x in xrange(12)]
[0, 1, 8, 42, 4, 25, 216, 42, 8, 81, 1000, 42]
```

Here is how each value is calculated:

```
[
 0,     # x is 0, x%4 is 0, so g(x) becomes (lambda x:x*1)(0) or 0*1
 1,     # x is 1, x%4 is 1, so g(x) becomes (lambda x:x*x)(1) or 1*1
 8,     # x is 2, x%4 is 2, so g(x) becomes (lambda x:x*x*x)(2) or 2*2*2
 42,    # x is 3, x%4 is 3, so g(x) becomes (lambda x:42)(3) or 42
 4,     # x is 4, x%4 is 0, so g(x) becomes (lambda x:x*1)(4) or 4*1
 25,    # x is 5, x%4 is 1, so g(x) becomes (lambda x:x*x)(5) or 5*5
 216,   # x is 6, x%4 is 2, so g(x) becomes (lambda x:x*x*x)(6) or 6*6*6
 42,    # x is 7, x%4 is 3, so g(x) becomes (lambda x:42)(7) or 42
 8,     # x is 8, x%4 is 0, so g(x) becomes (lambda x:x*1)(8) or 8*1
 81,    # x is 9, x%4 is 1, so g(x) becomes (lambda x:x*x)(9) or 9*9
 1000,  # x is 10, x%4 is 2, so g(x) becomes (lambda x:x*x*x)(10) or 10*10*10
 42     # x is 11, x%4 is 3, so g(x) becomes (lambda x:42)(11) or 42
]
```

Basically `g(x)` calls one of the functions in the list with `x` as the argument, when called in a list comprehension with `xrange` it will cycle through the functions, with every fourth call being the same function.

I know that this is just an exercise to aid in understanding Python, but you should note that this is horribly inefficient code, as all four functions are recreated on each call to `g()`.  If you actually needed this behavior it would be better to just create a function with `def` that contains several `if` statements (which would make the code much more readable as well).

Comment: It's a homework exam from the Learn Python meetup group here in Austin Texas.  This is a very helpful answer.  The instructor described it as a passive aggressive exercise, and I was stumped trying to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this to get a better idea as to what's happening (leave a comment if you need further explanation)

```
In [44]: g = lambda x:[lambda x:x*1, lambda x:x*x, lambda x:x*x*x, lambda x:42][x%4](x)

In [45]: {x:g(x) for x in xrange(12)}
Out[45]: 
{0: 0,
 1: 1,
 2: 8,
 3: 42,
 4: 4,
 5: 25,
 6: 216,
 7: 42,
 8: 8,
 9: 81,
 10: 1000,
 11: 42}
```